# Configuration Variables in Play! Framework

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play!, and wrote my first application. This app has a set of URL's it depends of, to pull data from and also to return valid URLs on the XML responses.

This app needs to run in different environments (Dev, Staging and Prod), and each environment will require its own set of URLs.

I guess the place to define this set of URLs is in the application.conf file. However I don't seem to find out how, and later access them through the normal classes.

As a related point, I don't want to use Framework IDs as we will deploying this as a WAR, and it will be easier to have an instance of the aplication.conf file per environment.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this post - [Playframework route file: Separate Production routes from Dev routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699955/playframework-route-file-separate-production-routes-from-dev-routes/6703337#6703337)

Take the approach in that post, but rather than using `Play.mode.isDev()`, use the configuration, such as `Play.configuration.get('item-from-app-conf')`

Comment: Thanks lots! And, can I create any number of variables in the application.conf ? i.e. %myapp.servers.url=http://www.google.com

Comment: yes, you can do whatever you need to, and read many values from the conf.