# Different routes for prod and dev in play 2.0

Tags: deployment, routes, playframework-2.0

My Play 2.0 application runs under different directories during development and in production:

During dev we use `/`, in production it runs as `/crm/`.

**Is it possible to define a "root directory" of some sort for play?**

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699955/playframework-route-file-separate-production-routes-from-dev-routes/6703337#6703337) suggests using the `isDev()` sort of methods and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358286/how-to-use-war-context-in-configuration-file-of-play-framework) to use a config variable, but it seems like the routes file no longer allows code inclusion: adding `%{ }`—style tags to the routes file results in compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems to be no other solution, I decided to go with a shell script that modifies the routes file on deployment and adds the necessary prefix to every route.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.0 or 2.0.1 you can't do it.

If you use the trunk-version you can define a property:

```
application.context="/AwesomePlayApplication"
```

This property can be set by in the usual way at production. 
But this is only possible with the future version.

Comment: Unfortunately we're still on the 2.1 release, so this doesn't help me

Comment: Then I fear you have a problem. Perhaps you can hosted the app under `crm.myCompany.com` instead of `www.myCompany.com/crm`